# ajax call not working with one click

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have a code in html:
**HTML:**

```
<div  id="all" aria-expanded="true">all</div>
```

and i want when this div was clicked, the ajax call:

**AJAX:**

```
$("#all").click(function () {

    $( "#adv-article-list" ).empty();
    $("#adv-article-list-pagination").empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_index.php', 
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {name: 1},
        success: function(data)
        {
            arr_db=data;
        }
    });
    function(arr_db);
})
```

My code worked correctly, but not with one click. I must clicked twice on div. **why?**

**PHP:**

```
$userAnswer = $_POST['name'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname="db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM wp_moeee ORDER BY  ID DESC");
$ar=array();

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $ar[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}

echo json_encode($ar);
```

Comment: success callback is async, so the arr_db assignment hasn't happened yet

Comment: You should definitely check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: What is `function(arr_db);` supposed to do ?

Comment: Some function that uses ajax response (which does not exist in that moment).

Answer (score 0):

Because [jQuery $.ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is asynchronous by default.

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false.

Although you may change it:

> Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active.

First time you trigger click event this happens:

1. the ajax request has been sent, than
2. `function(arr_db);` has been executed with `arr_db` not set yet
3. ajax response triggered jQuery's `success` callback and `arr_db=data;`

Second time you trigger click event:

1. second ajax request has been sent, than
2. `function(arr_db);` has been executed, using `arr_db` from first response
3. second ajax response triggered jQuery's `success` callback and `arr_db=data;`

Comment: tanx a lot.
i changed  async to false.

Comment: In fact, you should keep asynchronous ajax call, show some spinner while waiting for response and put `function(arr_db)` inside `success` ajax callback function. That is the way programmers usually go.